# How to stop display in search results custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple custom post types. I need display `country` and `location` results. but currently show all post types results in `search.php` page. I need hide results for these post types `post ,page, experience, trip-theme`.

I m using default theme WordPress `Seventeen theme`

I have no idea how can do this. please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_in_custom_post_type' );

function search_in_custom_post_type( $query ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
              $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'country', 'location' ) );
         }   

         return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you register post type set one extra parameter for search.

**FOR custom post type.**

```
'exclude_from_search' => true,
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type